# The probability of getting a specific color from withdrawing cards experiment with prior knowledge about it

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

While I am restudying the conditional probability. I gave myself a test to absorb the intuitive sense of it. Unfortunately, I did not success to solve the problem that I made for myself.

Let us say we have 3 types of colored cards: Green, Blue and Red, are juxtaposed with each other. So, the probability of getting a green one is 5/15 = 1/3.

If I expose 3 green cards, where I can see the location of those 3 green cards. 
As follows:

-Before exposing 3 green cards (first case) --> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-- After exposing 3 green cards (second case)  --> XXXGXXGXXXXGXXX

X: Is a card that we don't know what its color.
G: A card with green color.

As you can see in the second case we know that the green cards are in the locations: 4,7,12.

Now, based on our update. What is the probability of getting a green card from those 15 cards in the second case?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me the circumstances you're describing. This part "I expose 3 green cards, where I can see the location of those 3 green cards. And I kept those exposed cards in the cards that I want to pick one card from them." is unclear

Comment: @Glen_b I've edited the question.

Comment: I'm still confused about what you are trying to ask, even after the edits.  What exactly are you trying to do inference on?  When you say "The probability of getting a green one is 1/3," are you saying that you know beforehand that 1/3 of the cards are green, or are you saying that's your prior belief before observing the three green cards?  Also, after you expose the green cards 4, 7 and 12, can you still select those cards on the next draw?  Are you thinking about a deck with a (nearly) infinite number of cards or some limited number of cards?

Comment: @AtALoss Sorry about that I've updated the question. the probability is 1/3 is the proabability of getting a green card before exposing those 3 cards, which is 5/15 = 1/3. Yes, After exposing the green cards I can select them. For your last question: It's just 15 cards

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your question is a bit ambiguous, so I will deal with some use cases:

**Case 1**) Given there are 12 unknown cards, what is the probability of picking a green card from these unknowns?

Answer: 2/12 = 1/6, as there are 2 remaining green cards among 12 unknown cards.

**Case 2**) Given there are 15 cards, and I chose one at random, what is the probability of picking a green card?

Answer: 5/15 = 1/3, as the random selection means having cards face up provides no additional information

**Case 3**) Given 3 revealed cards, and assuming that choosing a green card is a success, what is the probability of picking a green card?

Answer: 1, you just pick up one of the green cards that are face up :-)

Comment: My question is "Given there are 15 cards, and 3 of the green cards are exposed (I know there locations ) and I chose one at random, what is the probability of picking a green card?"

Comment: @hbak: that would be case 2). Sometimes extra information doesn't impact the probability of an event occurring.